Vue how to render image depending on a variable
I want to render images depending on the selection of the user. My code is like this:
<v-img class="wrapper" :src="'../assets/images/' + img" alt="">

<script>
export default{
  data(){
   return() {
    img:"img1.jpg"
   }
  }
 }
</script>

If I write the full path like src="../assets/images/img1.jpg"  It does work.
